QGIS crashes when I set the labels
I'm writing a script for QGIS, using the Python console. I noticed that when the script processes the rows about the label settings, when I delete the layer "terrFiltrati", QGIS crashes and this error appears.
Anyone knows why?
Here the code.
    labelSet  = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
    text_format.setSize(20)
    labelSet.setFormat(text_format)
    labelSet.fieldName = "NId"
    labelSet.enabled = True
    labelSet.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.OverPoint
    etichette = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(labelSet)
    layer_settings = QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling(labelSet)
    edificiIdonei.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    edificiIdonei.setLabeling(etichette)
    edificiIdonei.triggerRepaint()
    terrFiltrati.setLabelsEnabled(True)
    terrFiltrati.setLabeling(etichette)
    terrFiltrati.triggerRepaint()
    
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([aRispettoLayer])
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([edificiIdonei])
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([terrFiltrati])
    
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()



You can't use the same QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling instance to label two different layers.
You currently have:
edificiIdonei.setLabeling(etichette)

terrFiltrati.setLabeling(etichette)

I suspect that's the problem. Instead you can use:
edificiIdonei.setLabeling(etichette)

terrFiltrati.setLabeling(etichette.clone())

Cloning the QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabling as in the second line should solve your problem.
You are also using the same QgsPalLayerSettings for two different QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabling instances (etichette and layer_settings) which may cause a similar issue -- you should use a unique QgsPalLayerSettings for each QgsVectorLayerSimpleLabeling instance.
